# Qual é a diferença entre o IDLE Python 3.5 Shell e Python 3.5 (CMD)?

Tags: python, windows

Instalei Python para Windows na minha máquina mas fiquei com uma dúvida: Tanto o IDLE Python 3.5 (Shell) e o Python 3.5 (CMD) foram instalados. Há diferença entre eles? Algum deles tenho mais recurso ou algo do tipo?

Answer (score 2):

Há diferenças na usabilidade, em teoria você é capaz de realizar as mesmas operações tanto no IDLE(ou em outro editor de texto) como pelo prompt interativo.

A diferença é que pelo CMD você vai ter de executar seu código linha por linha, a cada enter pressionado* o seu código é avaliado e retornado com um valor, o que é ótimo para pequenos testes, porém caso você erre uma linha não há como voltar e alterar o conteúdo, não há um meio intuitivo e prático para salvar seu código, entre diversos outros "problemas". Debuggar o código me parece inviável pelo CMD também, mas não é algo que posso afirmar com certeza, nunca tentei. 
Basicamente o CMD é indicado para que você realize pequenos testes, veja o resultado de uma operação, cheque como um método funciona, etc.. Para consultas, mesmo.

Já o IDLE oferece funções úteis como *highlight* de texto, *autocomplete* para métodos e variáveis, entre outras funções que facilitam o seu trabalho como programador.

*Se você executar um bloco como um "for", por exemplo, você vai poder inserir múltiplos comandos antes que o prompt avalie sua expressão